# Kernel configuration is invalid - raspberry rtl8812au driver

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi, kernel, wifi, driver

Been looking everywhere and tried a lot of things but can't get it to work. A **BIG** Banana to the one which will save me.

**Objective**. Install the rtl8812au driver on my Raspberry 4

**Steps:**

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
cd rtl8812au
sudo vi Makefile

CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y
CONFIG_POWER_SAVING = n

sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

Then get the following error either through make or sudo ./install.sh

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/linux-ff93994fb3f92070d8521d709ad04675ecaa5817'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

Makefile:632: include/config/auto.conf: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:704: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/linux-ff93994fb3f92070d8521d709ad04675ecaa5817'
make: *** [Makefile:1068: modules] Error 2
```

Of course, I tried make oldconfig && make prepare which returned:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'oldconfig'.  Stop.
```

Comment: You need to run `'make oldconfig && make prepare'` in the directory with the **kernel sources** (`/root/linux-ff93994fb3f92070d8521d709ad04675ecaa5817` in your case), not from the directory with the module. Moreover, the module will work only with the kernel, compiled from these sources. So you need to not only prepare them for the module building, but you need to build the kernel too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: you're my savior here. Indeed I had to go in the directory with the kernel sources and make from that directory. Took quite some time on the Raspberry Pi 4 but once everything was built, I've been able to properly 'make' the driver. Thank you so much for your kind help - much appreciated !